# Things to consider before reinstalling Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, filesystems, operating-systems, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So, I'm planning on reinstalling windows. Long story short, windows insider expired and I cannot opt out of it anymore. Now I just keep getting notifications about it.

I'm just wondering what are the things that I need to consider before going all in with the reinstallation? Will all the memory be wiped out? I have not partitioned my drive. Do I need to backup all my data? if so then what would you recommend using to do so?
Will all of my applications be wiped out? Is it possible to recover them in a quick manner? I just don't want to have to reinstall everything manually one by one...

What is the worst thing that could happen if I reinstall the OS?
Here's the OS build info for anyone who's interested.
The machine is a Dell XPS 15 7590 running Windows 10 Education Insider Preview and the Version is 2004. I just don't need Windows Insider anymore. But now the notifications are just so annoying.

[image: OS build info]

Comment: You should always back up your data whether you are reinstalling or not. Disk drives can fail without warning.

Comment: If you opt out of Windows Insider, you will be returned to Production Windows at the first opportunity. So you do not have to reinstall if you do not wish to, and returning to Production will not lose any apps or data. It will be quite seamless.

Comment: @John - That only is true if the author isn’t on a expired build.  The fact the question mention their build has expired tells me their system hasn’t updated in months

Comment: If there are notifications coming (as said in Question), then the notifications should allow back into Insider if desired or opt out if desired. I think that would be the case.

Comment: Run *Settings > System > About* and look under "Windows specif‌ications". Is the "Version" set to "2004"?

Comment: When you reinstall all programs which you have installed will be cleared your data will  be wiped out since you have only one partition when you install windows in that partition it will clear every thing.

Comment: @harrymc yes the version is clearly 2004, installed on 5/9/2020, OS build 19624.10000.

Comment: @John no that never happened. There are notification but it leads me to a link that tells me that I need to reinstall... sadly...

Comment: At this point, backup and fresh install is all that is left, so do that.

Comment: @John I mean that's what I'm trying to do... which is why I'm asking this question lol